# c++: Copying a boost::array

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, copy

Say I have

`boost::array<std::set<std::string>, 100000> arr1, arr2;`

After populating `arr1` I'm doing `arr2=arr1`.

Does this copy all the elements from `arr1` into `arr2` as stl containers do or is it just changing the `arr2` pointer to be pointing to the same array as `arr1`?

In case the first option is correct, what happens when I pass `arr1` to a function by value?

Comment: It copies all the elements. When you pass `arr1` by value, you make a copy (unless there is scope for copy elision, which seems unlikely).

Comment: So also when passing by value, all the elements are duplicated?

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide a reference to documentation?

Comment: See @jessegood's answer. The same applies to standard library containers (including `std::array`). Containers own their own copies of things, which means that when they are copied, each copy must own its contents, which means the contents need to be copied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a [reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/array.html):

```
template<typename U> array& operator=(const array<U, N>& other);

Effects:
    std::copy(rhs.begin(),rhs.end(), begin())
```

Note what the `Effects` are. Also, you should consider `std::array` instead of `boost::array` if you're implementation supports it.